# MySQL - Group activities by label and by hour

Tags: mysql, datetime

I've an **activities** table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE `prova` (
 `date` date NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activity` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

with these data:

| date | time | duration | activity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-19 | 17:10:00 | 50 | test0 |
| 2023-06-19 | 17:11:00 | 10 | test0 |
| 2023-06-19 | 17:12:10 | 12 | test1 |
| 2023-06-19 | 17:59:00 | 120 | test2 |

I need to create a query that returns an overview of activities grouped by activity name and hour. Something like that:

| date | total_duration | activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-19 17:00:00 | 60 | test0 |
| 2023-06-19 17:00:00 | 12 | test1 |
| 2023-06-19 17:00:00 | 60 | test2 |
| 2023-06-19 18:00:00 | 60 | test2 |

Using this query:

```
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP(date, time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') as date, 
           SUM(duration) AS total_duration, activity
    FROM prova
    GROUP BY activity, date, hour(time)
    ORDER BY time
```

I'm able to get these results:

| date | total_duration | activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-19 17:00:00 | 60 | test0 |
| 2023-06-19 17:00:00 | 12 | test1 |
| 2023-06-19 17:00:00 | 120 | test2 |

But how can I manage the fact that the last record exceeds the hour range and should be splitted into two records ?

NOTE: if possible, I wouldn't use a procedural query

**EDIT**
MySQL server version: 5.6
Column **duration** is in seconds

Comment: It's not easy to split a row in SQL like this. You'd probably be better off fixing it in the language you use to display the results. Whenever duration is more than 60, create additional rows for the extra hours.

Comment: @Barmar it's even harder than that. What about a time of `17:50` and a duration of `20` minutes. That gets two calendar-hour entries in the result set, each ten minutes long.

Comment: Which MySQL version do you use? It's helpful to know because [common table expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) will help keep this query's code someplace between ridiculous and ludicrous.  Please [edit] your question.

Comment: A pure SQL solution will require joining with a table containing all the hours, and using time functions to detetermine whether a particular hour is within `time + duration`.

Comment: Updated question with additional infos

Answer (score 0):

Your table has activities with durations. Your desired result set summarizes them by hour. (I renamed your `date` and `time` columns because it's easier to write code when columns aren't named with reserved words in the language.)

Here's how to generate your result set with your grandmother's pure SQL (MySQL 5.6 is advanced in years). It's a complex task, with several subtasks.

## Calendar virtual table

We need a calendar table, a table with one row for each hour of all the relevant days. We'll use that table later. We call it a "virtual" table because we'll generate it with a subquery rather than creating a permanent table.

First, let's get a table with the relevant dates. Let's assume that no `duration` exceeds 24 hours (1440 minutes). Here's the subquery. With a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nwzjzrJc). This gets all the dates in your table, and all those dates' tomorrows with the UNION.

```sql
              SELECT DISTINCT DATE(dt) dt FROM prova
              UNION
              SELECT DISTINCT DATE(dt) + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM prova
```

Next we need a virtual table of hours, integers 0 .. 23.  This is verbose in SQL. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jr28DzYO)

```sql
    SELECT 0 hr UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
    UNION ALL SELECT  4 UNION ALL SELECT  5 UNION ALL SELECT  6 UNION ALL SELECT  7
    UNION ALL SELECT  8 UNION ALL SELECT  9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11
    UNION ALL SELECT 12 UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15
    UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 18 UNION ALL SELECT 19
    UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 21 UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23
```

Next we CROSS JOIN those two subqueries to get the calendar table, with one row per hour. Here I abbreviated the subqueries for readability. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FL5MMuyi). This contains two columns, `hourstart` and `hourend`.

```sql
        SELECT dts.dt + INTERVAL hrs.hr HOUR hourstart,
               dts.dt + INTERVAL hrs.hr + 1 HOUR hourend
        FROM **the dates** dts
        CROSS JOIN **the hours** hrs
```

## Activity virtual table

Next we need a subquery to transform your `prova` table into something that's easier to handle, with start and stop datestamps. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eZMbJf3y).

```sql
        SELECT ADDTIME(prova.dt, prova.tm) start,
               ADDTIME(prova.dt, prova.tm) + INTERVAL prova.duration MINUTE stop,
               prova.duration,
               prova.activity
          FROM prova
```

Now we join your activity data to the calendar table, so we get one row of output for each hour in which each activity occurred. An activity occurred within an hour if it stops after the hour starts AND it starts before the hour ends.

Again I'm abbreviating the subqueries. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zmG_s9xp).

```sql
SELECT calendar.hourstart,
       activity.start,
       activity.duration,
       activity.activity
  FROM (
    **calendar**
  ) calendar
  JOIN (
     **activity**
  ) activity ON activity.start < calendar.hourend
            AND activity.stop  > calendar.hourstart
```

## Hourly durations

Now we need to figure out how many minutes of the activity's duration occur within each calendar hour. We need [TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, end)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to compute this.

We have four cases:

1. `activity.start < hourstart AND activity.stop >= hourend`. The activity was in progress the whole hour. So the `duration` is 60.
2. `activity.start < hourstart AND activity.stop < hourend`. The activity started before the hour and ended within the hour. So the `duration` is `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, hourstart, stop)`.
3. `activity.start >= hourstart AND activity.stop >= hourend`. The activity started within the hour, but did not end within the hour. So the `duration` is  `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, hourend)`.
4. The activity started and ended within the hour. So the `duration` is the original duration.

We can write this expression using CASE WHEN THEN. Here's a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aJVJCKTj) doing this computation.

```sql
CASE 
WHEN activity.start < hourstart AND activity.stop >= hourend
    THEN 60
WHEN activity.start < hourstart AND activity.stop < hourend
    THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, hourstart, activity.stop)
WHEN activity.start >= hourstart AND activity.stop >= hourend
    THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, activity.start, hourend)
ELSE activity.duration END
```

## Aggregation

Finally we have to use GROUP BY to aggregate the results.

```sql
SELECT hourstart, activity, COUNT(*) concurrent, SUM(duration) duration
  FROM **that big query**
 GROUP BY activity, hourstart
 ORDER BY activity, hourstart
```

## Result

Putting this all together we get this query. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SK16ngNi). "Hairball" is the technical term for it.

```sql
SELECT hourstart, activity, COUNT(*) concurrent, SUM(duration) duration
 FROM (
SELECT calendar.hourstart,
      activity.start,
      activity.stop,
      activity.duration total_duration,
      activity.activity,
      CASE 
      WHEN activity.start < hourstart AND activity.stop >= hourend THEN 60
      WHEN activity.start < hourstart AND activity.stop < hourend THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, hourstart, activity.stop)
      WHEN activity.start >= hourstart AND activity.stop >= hourend THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, activity.start, hourend)
      ELSE activity.duration END duration

 FROM (
       SELECT dts.dt + INTERVAL hrs.hr HOUR hourstart,
              dts.dt + INTERVAL hrs.hr + 1 HOUR hourend
       FROM (
               SELECT DISTINCT DATE(dt) AS dt FROM prova
               UNION
               SELECT DISTINCT DATE(dt) + INTERVAL 24 HOUR FROM prova
       ) dts 
       CROSS JOIN (
             SELECT 0 hr UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
             UNION ALL SELECT  4 UNION ALL SELECT  5 UNION ALL SELECT  6 UNION ALL SELECT  7
             UNION ALL SELECT  8 UNION ALL SELECT  9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11
             UNION ALL SELECT 12 UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15
             UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 18 UNION ALL SELECT 19
             UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 21 UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23          
      ) hrs
 ) calendar
 JOIN (
       SELECT ADDTIME(prova.dt, prova.tm) start,
              ADDTIME(prova.dt, prova.tm) + INTERVAL prova.duration MINUTE stop,
              prova.duration,
              prova.activity
         FROM prova  
 ) activity ON activity.start < calendar.hourend
         AND activity.stop > calendar.hourstart
) hour_by_hour
GROUP BY activity, hourstart
ORDER BY activity, hourstart
```

## More modern SQL makes it easier to read

If we had MySQL version 8 or a recent version of MariaDB, we could use [common table expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) like so, making the query quite a bit easier to read. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YDQRCh39). In addition, MariaDB has built in [sequences](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-storage-engine/) like `seq_0_to_23`.

```sql
-- Dates
WITH dts AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT DATE(dt) AS dt FROM prova
   UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT DATE(dt) + INTERVAL 24 HOUR FROM prova
),
-- Hours
seq_0_to_23 AS (
  SELECT 0 seq UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
  UNION ALL SELECT  4 UNION ALL SELECT  5 UNION ALL SELECT  6 UNION ALL SELECT  7
  UNION ALL SELECT  8 UNION ALL SELECT  9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11
  UNION ALL SELECT 12 UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15
  UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 18 UNION ALL SELECT 19
  UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 21 UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23
),
-- Calendar virtual table
calendar AS (
  SELECT dts.dt + INTERVAL hrs.seq HOUR hourstart,
         dts.dt + INTERVAL hrs.seq + 1 HOUR hourend
    FROM dts
   CROSS JOIN seq_0_to_23 hrs
),
-- Activity virtual table
activity AS (
  SELECT ADDTIME(prova.dt, prova.tm) start,
         ADDTIME(prova.dt, prova.tm) + INTERVAL prova.duration MINUTE stop,
         prova.duration,
         prova.activity
    FROM prova  
),
-- Activities broken out hour-by-hour
hour_by_hour AS (
  SELECT calendar.hourstart,
         activity.start,
         activity.stop,
         activity.duration total_duration,
         activity.activity,
         CASE 
         WHEN activity.start < hourstart AND activity.stop >= hourend THEN 60
         WHEN activity.start < hourstart AND activity.stop < hourend THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, hourstart, activity.stop)
         WHEN activity.start >= hourstart AND activity.stop >= hourend THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, activity.start, hourend)
         ELSE activity.duration END duration
   FROM calendar
   JOIN activity ON activity.start < calendar.hourend
                AND activity.stop > calendar.hourstart
)
-- Aggregated activities hour by hour
SELECT hourstart, activity, COUNT(*) concurrent, SUM(duration) duration
  FROM hour_by_hour
 GROUP BY activity, hourstart
 ORDER BY activity, hourstart;
```